# Expectation and variance without replacement

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling, variance

Let $X_{N_1},\cdots,X_{N_n}$ is a sample without replacement from the set $\{1,2,\cdots,N\}$, and let $\bar X_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_{N_{i}}/n$. Then, how one can find $E(\bar X_n)$, $Var(\bar X_n)$, $\max_{1\le i\le N} (X_i-\bar X_n)^2$, and $\sum_{i=1}^N(X_i-\bar X_n)^2$?

Answer (score 1):

1. Expectation is linear if the expectations exist:

$$E[\bar X_n]=E[\sum_{i=1}^n X_{N_{i}}/n] = \sum_{i=1}^n E[X_{N_{i}}]/n$$

2. Variance is sort of linear for independent random variables:

$$Var[\bar X_n]=Var[\sum_{i=1}^n X_{N_{i}}/n] = \sum_{i=1}^n Var[X_{N_{i}}]/n^2$$

If the random variables are not independent (from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties)):

[image]

3. $$\max_{1\le i\le N} (X_i-\bar X_n)^2$$

Statistically speaking, compute the values

$$(X_1-\bar X_n)^2, (X_2-\bar X_n)^2, ..., (X_n-\bar X_n)^2$$

then pick the highest.

Alternatively, we note that:

$$\max_{1\le i\le N} (X_i-\bar X_n)^2 = (\max_{1\le i\le N} |X_i-\bar X_n|)^2$$

so we can instead compute

$$|X_1-\bar X_n|, |X_2-\bar X_n|, ..., |X_n-\bar X_n|$$

then pick the highest and square it.

Probabilistically speaking, $\max_{1\le i\le N} (X_i-\bar X_n)^2$ is a random variable equal to

$(X_1-\bar X_n)^2$ if $(X_1-\bar X_n)^2 > (X_2-\bar X_n)^2, ..., (X_N-\bar X_n)^2$

$(X_2-\bar X_n)^2$ if $(X_2-\bar X_n)^2 > (X_1-\bar X_n)^2, (X_3-\bar X_n)^2, ..., (X_N-\bar X_n)^2$

$$\vdots$$

$(X_N-\bar X_n)^2$ if $(X_N-\bar X_n)^2 > (X_1-\bar X_n)^2, (X_2-\bar X_n)^2, ..., (X_{N-1}-\bar X_n)^2$

4. $$\sum_{i=1}^N(X_i-\bar X_n)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^N(X_i-\sum_{i=1}^n X_{N_{i}}/n)^2$$

Comment: Thank you very much BCLC. I have these derivatiins but want simplIfield answers for the set $\{1,2,\cdots, N\}$.

Comment: @Ahmed What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that $E (\bar X)$ would be $(N+1)/2$ or $N (N+1)/2$. Similarly, I required other answers.

Comment: @Ahmed Well, that depends on the distribution of the random variables

Comment: not really.  Since we have given a set of values $\{1,2,\cdots,N\}$ and know that sampling is without replacement, the probability of selection of the first unit would be $1/N$, second one $(N-1)/N$, and so on. To calculate expectation or other quantities, therefore, we multiply probability with its variable value $\{1,2,\cdots,N\}$.

Comment: Is it 1/N? I think you're assuming uniform distribution or something.  Is it (N-1)/N? I think that is a conditional probability of selection of the first

Comment: without replacement selection

Comment: @Ahmed What distribution is that? I've never heard of that

Comment: Please see http://www.emathzone.com/tutorials/basic-statistics/sampling-without-replacement.html

Comment: I know what 'without replacement' but I don't see how that's a 'distribution'. The probability of picking a ball in a bin of 10 balls is not 1/10.